# React Native Expo and AWS Amplify Auth: Getting Logged Out on Executing URI Scheme Command

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, aws-amplify

I am developing an application combining AWS Amplify with React Native Expo. When I execute the command `npx uri-scheme open "exp+sample://event/111sample" --android` on an Android emulator, I get logged out every time, even if I am logged in. This occurs during operational testing in a development build. Despite being logged in, executing this command seems to log me out.

I am looking for a way to maintain the logged-in state even after executing this command. If possible, I want to maintain the session state so that the user does not need to log in again.

To reproduce the situation, I follow these steps:

Log into the application using AWS Amplify's Auth.
Execute the above command to access a specific page in the application through the custom URI scheme.
Upon executing this command, I find myself logged out.
Is there any solution or recommendation related to this?